# Find $\lim\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)$

Tags: limits

Find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)$$

Answer (score 14):

[Hint: Try rationalizing the denominators.](http://images.hayneedle.com/mgen/master%3aZHUL053.jpg)

Comment: @DavidH I've been waiting for a chance to use it. Haha.

Comment: i did that.. thank you for your hint..@CameronWilliams

Comment: You're very welcome @David

Comment: The link appears, thus the whole answer, to be broken.

Comment: ... or not accessible $\:\ddot\frown$

Answer (score 8):

From the Hint given by @cameron Williams, I did the following.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{3}}{-2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}}{-2}+\ldots+\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}-\sqrt{2n+1}}{-2}\right)$$
Now the second and consectives gets cancelled. So,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{-2}-\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{-2}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{n}}}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$